# How can I make each instance of a perl script have its own unique id?

Tags: perl, mechanize, uuid, plex

I have a perl script that connects to the Plex API. It logs in and performs certain actions (mostly working).

However, the Plex API suggests (insists?) that each instance of the script send a unique ID, such that if I share this script with anyone else they should use a different string.

In the interests of keeping this simple, I don't want to have some configuration file that keeps that value outside of the script. I also can't leave a value hard-coded in, no one who downloads this will change it.

Could the perl script modify itself?

If I were to declare it as such:

```
my $uuid = 1;
```

... then could I not check immediately afterward if this value is equal to 1, and if so overwrite that with a randomly generated uuid? The script would then exit, but somehow re-invoke itself (so the user doesn't have to run it a second time).

Is there a safe way to do this? Alternatively, is there a better way to accomplish the goal without using this method?

Comment: Do you need a different ID for every run, or every installation? Either way, use a module like [Data::GUID](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::GUID).

Comment: Per installation. Not per run.

Comment: Is this a Linux or Windows question, or could it be a mixture?

Comment: It's a perl question. If I make this script available to others... I have no clue what platform they may run it from.

Answer (score 1):

Make the last line of your script `__DATA__` and append the ID to the script either at installation or first run.  Reading from the special `<DATA>` handle reads the data segment of a script.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`UUID::Tiny`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?UUID%3A%3ATiny) to generate a [random UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29):

```
use UUID::Tiny;   
my $uuid = create_UUID(UUID_V4);
```

To preserve the UUID between invocations, you'll have to modify the script itself. The answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562586/can-a-perl-script-modify-itself) might be helpful.

Comment: This doesn't accomplish the task. Each time it runs, it will get a new value. It needs to be the same value for any given user, every time they run it. But it needs to be a different value for every user. Low-overhead, single file script.

Comment: @JohnO Generate the ID as part of the installation process.

Comment: It's not anything that requires an "installation process". It's a single-file script fewer than 150 lines of code. Half of that comments and whitespace. That's overkill.

Comment: @JohnO Then generate it the first time the script is run and store it, either in the script itself or in a separate file (my preference).

Comment: Generating it the first time is easy. Storing it... I was asking how to do that creatively. Even if impractical, it was an interesting idea but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: @JohnO The easiest way would be: if ID file exists, read ID from file; if not, generate new ID and write to file.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

You say in the comments that you want a different unique ID [*"per installation"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954976/how-can-i-make-each-instance-of-a-perl-script-have-its-own-unique-id/37958632#comment63358824_37954976), but you also say that [*"it needs to be the same value for any given user"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954976/how-can-i-make-each-instance-of-a-perl-script-have-its-own-unique-id/37958632#comment63358805_37955103), so I'm no longer sure that my answer will satisfy your requirements

---

I suggest that you use the system UUID returned by `dmidecode`. Of course you will need to have it installed on your computer, and there's a parser module for it on CPAN called [`Parse::DMIDecode`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::DMIDecode)

It's slightly more complex if you have to support Windows systems. You can use [*DmiDecode for Windows*](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/dmidecode.htm), which is available as a ready-built binary, but the parser module explicitly checks that there are no colons (amongst other things) in the path to the `demidecode` executable, so a call to the `probe` method won't work. Instead you must call `demidecode` and pass the result to the `parse` method

This short example works fine on both Linux and Windows

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Parse::DMIDecode;

my $decoder = Parse::DMIDecode->new;
$decoder->parse(qx{dmidecode});

say $decoder->keyword('system-uuid');
```

#### output

```
35304535-3439-4344-3232-3245FFFFFFFF
```